# D8 - show view in comments depending on user role

Tags: views, users, comments

how i have to set up a view with Drupal 8 to show a field in the comments when the user_role is NOT "admin".

im not sure what kind of relationship and contextfilter i need to to this?

background: i want to show a label under the user_image of the comments 
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

There is many ways to do it, but the simplest way is to check if user is admin or has exact role..

`global $user;
   if ( !in_array('administrator', $user->roles) ) {
     ... do something ...
   }`

OR

```
if( $user->uid !== 1 ){
  ... do something ...
}
```

OR

`path_is_admin(current_path())`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have all of the answer. However I think you need to create a user view instead of a content view. That might be the key to solving it.

Comment: the problem is: how the view recognize the author (user) of the comment